# Group action : $ g * g^{-1} = e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Okay so from group definition we know that if $(G,\times)$ is a grooup then : $g\times g^{-1} = e$. My problem is does the same hold for group action "$*$" ?
If $"*": G \times X \rightarrow X $ is an action , how can I prove :
$g*g^{-1} = e$?
My book does not change notation when referring to action and it's highly confusing to me because I feel like we use group operation properties as they hold for actions.
I tried to prove it myself but I am stuck:
By the first property of action: $e*g = g , \forall g \in G$
$\implies e*(g\times g^{-1}) = g \times g^{-1}$ and that's not helpful...

Comment: $X$ is a set which, in principle, may have nothing to do with $G$. So having $g^{-1}$ as the second argument of $*$ or $e$ as its result doesn't make sense.

Comment: The expression "$g*g^{-1}$" isn't even well-formed in this context: it only makes sense to write "$a*b$" if $a\in G$ and $b\in X$, and that's not the case here.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: it's by Fraleigh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a group action, $e * x =x$ and $(gh)*x = g*(h*x)$.

''how can I prove : $g∗g^{−1}=e$?''

The group can act on itself by left multiplication (here $X=G$): $g*h = gh$. Then $g*g^{-1} = gg^{-1}=e$ by definition of the inverse.

Comment: my book has no different notation for action and group operation so because it said : $(gh)x = g(hx)$ , I supposed it meant : $(g*h)*x = g*(h*x)$ so I was confused, but you made it clear

Comment: (g∗h)∗x=g∗(h∗x). Here $gh= g*h$ is group multiplication, while $(gh)*x$ and $h*x$ means group action.

Comment: So are you saying that you defined group action at this case to be the same as group operation ? So what I asked is not generally true?

Comment: 1) Yes, I did. 2) No its not.

Comment: well now you made it clear, thank you!